# In bash, how to batch show the text of certain line in files?

Tags: bash, sed, xargs

I want to batch show the text of certain line of files in certain directory, usually this can be done with the following commands:

```
    for file in `find ./ -name "results.txt"`; 
    do
        sed -n '12p' < ${file}; 
    done
```

In the 12th line of each file names "results.txt", there is the text I want to output.

But, I wonder that if we can use the pipeline command to do this operation. I have tried the following command:

```
    find ./ -name "results.txt" | xargs sed -n '12p'
```

or

```
    find ./ -name "results.txt" | xargs sed -n '12p' < {} \;
```

But neither works fine. 
Could you give some advice or recommend some references, please? 
All are welcome, Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
find ./ -name results.txt -exec sed '12!d' {} ';'
```

Comment: +1, but `sed '12q;d'` is preferable for performance reasons (exits right after printing the line of interest).

Comment: @mklement0, thank you very much for your suggestion of improving the performance!

Answer (score 3):

[@Steven Penny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24196705/45375) is the **most elegant and best-performing solution**, but to shed some light on **why your solution didn't work**:

```
find ./ -name "results.txt" | xargs sed -n '12p'
```

causes *all* filenames<sup>(1)</sup> to be passed *at once*<sup>(2)</sup> to `sed`. Since `sed` counts lines *cumulatively, across input files*, **only *1* line will be printed for *all* input files**, namely line 12 from the *first* input file.

Keeping in mind that `find`'s `-exec` action is the best solution, if you still wanted to solve this problem with `xargs`, you'd have to **use `xarg`'s `-I` option as follows, so as to ensure that `sed` is called *once per input line (filename)*** (`%` is a self-chosen placeholder):

```
find ./ -name "results.txt" | xargs -I % sed -n '12q;d' %
```

**Footnotes:**

- (1) with word splitting applied, which would break with paths with embedded spaces, but that's a separate issue.
- (2)  assuming they don't make the entire command exceed the max. length of a command line; either way, *multiple* filenames are passed at once.

As an aside: **parsing command output with `for` as in your first snippet is NEVER a good idea** - see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: This answer helps me a lot! Thank you very much for so detail explanations for better answer!

Comment: @Nicolas: I'm glad to hear it; my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `xargs` results in running `sed` with multiple file arguments. But as you can see, `sed` doesn't reset the record number to 1 when it starts reading a new file. For example, try running the following command against files with more than 12 lines each.

```
sed -n '12p'  x.txt y.txt
```

If you want to use xargs, you might consider using awk:

```
find . -name 'results.txt' | xargs awk 'FNR==12'
```

P.S: I personally like using the `for` loop.

Comment: The `awk` idea is clever, but to make it work with paths with embedded spaces, you'd have to use `find . -name 'results.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 awk 'FNR==12'`. By contrast, parsing lines of a file or command output with `for` is NEVER a good idea - see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001